# Android List View and SQLite

Tags: java, android

[image]I want populate list View from SQLite database .I'm using join query with two tables.In my first table there are three entries are available but my list view is not showing any data and print the log cat of count the cursor is zero in if statement.What is the problem with database. Can some one help me please.Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
public class Employee_List extends Activity
{

    Context mContext;
    Employee emp;
    ImageView imgButtonBack;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    ListView listEmployee;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;


    private SQLiteDatabase newDB;

 public static final String EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_TABLE = "employee_details";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.staff_employee_list);

        listEmployee = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        openAndQueryDatabase();


        private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
        try {
            DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
            newDB = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            ArrayList<Employee> EmployeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();  
            String finalQuery = "select employee_details.Emp_id AS EMPID,  employee_details.staff_emp_name AS NAME , employee_details.department AS DEPT , employee_details.designation AS DESIGNATION ,"
                      +" (SUM(performance.performance_rate_one + performance.performance_rate_two + performance.performance_rate_three + performance.performance_rate_four + performance.performance_rate_five) / 5 ) AS TOTAL_RATE"
                      +" FROM employee_details left join performance "
                      +" ON employee_details.Emp_id = performance.empid"
                      +" GROUP BY employee_details.Emp_id"
                      +" ORDER BY TOTAL_RATE  DESC";

            Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery(finalQuery, null);

            if (c != null )
            {
                int count = c.getCount();
                Log.e("count " , " = " + count);
                if  (c.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do 
                    {
                        Employee EmployeeListItems = new Employee();  

                        EmployeeListItems.setEmployeeId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("EMPID")));
                        EmployeeListItems.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NAME")));
                        EmployeeListItems.setDepartment(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DEPT")));
                        EmployeeListItems.setDesignation(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DESIGNATION")));
                        EmployeeListItems.setPerformancerate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("TOTAL_RATE")));
                        EmployeeList.add(EmployeeListItems);     

                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                } 
            }   

            EmployeeList_Adapter contactListAdapter = new EmployeeList_Adapter(Employee_List.this, EmployeeList); 
            listEmployee.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);  
            contactListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } 


        catch (SQLiteException se )
        {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
        } 

        finally 
        {
            if (newDB != null) 
                //newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_TABLE);
                newDB.close();
        }

    }


}




Here is my DataBaseHelper Class


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase;

        //Database name
       public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "EmployeeReview.db";

       //Database Version
       static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

       public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

       //Table Name
       public static final String REGISTRATION_TABLE = "registration_form";
       public static final String EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_TABLE = "employee_details";
       public static final String EMPLOYEE_PERFORMANCE_TABLE = "performance";


      //Table REGISTRATION_TABLE columns Name
       public static final String Reg_ID = "reg_id";
       public static final String Company_Name = "company_name";
       public static final String Employee_Name = "employee_name";
       public static final String Company_Website = "company_website";
       public static final String Contact_No = "contact_number";
       public static final String Email_Id = "email";
       public static final String Financial_Year = "financial_year";


       //Table EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_TABLE columns Name
       public static final String Staff_Emp_ID = "Emp_id";
       public static final String Staff_Employee_Name = "staff_emp_name";
       public static final String Department = "department";
       public static final String Designation = "designation";


     //Table RATING_BAR_TABLE columns Name
       public static final String Performance_Id = "performance_id";
       public static final String Performer_Id = "empid";
       public static final String Performer_Name = "performer_name";
       public static final String Performance_Rate_One = "performance_rate_one";
       public static final String Performance_Rate_Two = "performance_rate_two";
       public static final String Performance_Rate_Three = "performance_rate_three";
       public static final String Performance_Rate_Four = "performance_rate_four";
       public static final String Performance_Rate_Five = "performance_rate_five";
       public static final String Performance_Month = "performance_month";
       public static final String Performance_Only_Month = "second_date";
       public static final String Performance_Year = "year";




       @Override
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String  CREATE_REGISTRATION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ REGISTRATION_TABLE + "("
                  + Reg_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
                  + Company_Name + " TEXT,"
                  + Employee_Name + " TEXT, "
                  + Company_Website+ " TEXT, "
                  + Contact_No + " TEXT, "
                  + Email_Id + " TEXT, "
                  + Financial_Year + " TEXT "+");";
          db.execSQL(CREATE_REGISTRATION_TABLE);

          String  CREATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_TABLE + "("
                  + Staff_Emp_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
                  + Staff_Employee_Name + " TEXT,"
                  + Department + " TEXT, "
                  + Designation + " TEXT "+");";
          db.execSQL(CREATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_TABLE);

          final String  CREATE_PERFORMANCE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ EMPLOYEE_PERFORMANCE_TABLE + "("
                  + Performance_Id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
                  + Performer_Id + " TEXT,"
                  + Performer_Name + " TEXT, "
                  + Performance_Rate_One + " TEXT, "
                  + Performance_Rate_Two + " TEXT, "
                  + Performance_Rate_Three + " TEXT, "
                  + Performance_Rate_Four + " TEXT, "
                  + Performance_Rate_Five + " TEXT, "
                  + Performance_Month + " TEXT, "
                  + Performance_Only_Month + " TEXT, "
                  + Performance_Year + " TEXT "+");";

          db.execSQL(CREATE_PERFORMANCE_TABLE);

    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME);
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + REGISTRATION_TABLE);
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_TABLE);
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + EMPLOYEE_PERFORMANCE_TABLE);
         onCreate(db);
    }



    public boolean insertRegstrationDetails(String strCompanyName, String strEmployeeName, 
                                            String strCompanyWebSite, String strContactNumber,
                                            String strEMail,String strFinancialYear)
       {
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
          ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

          contentValues.put(Company_Name, strCompanyName);
          contentValues.put(Employee_Name, strEmployeeName);
          contentValues.put(Company_Website, strCompanyWebSite);    
          contentValues.put(Contact_No, strContactNumber);
          contentValues.put(Email_Id, strEMail);
          contentValues.put(Financial_Year, strFinancialYear);


          db.insert(REGISTRATION_TABLE, null, contentValues);
          db.close();
          return true;
       }

/**********************************************************Staff Employee Details***********************************************/   
        public boolean insertStaffEmployeeDetails(String strStaffEmployeeName, String strDepartment, String strDesignation)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

            contentValues.put(Staff_Employee_Name, strStaffEmployeeName);
            contentValues.put(Department, strDepartment);
            contentValues.put(Designation, strDesignation); 

            db.insert(EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_TABLE, null, contentValues);
            db.close();
            return true;
        }


         public List<String> getStaffEmployeeName(){
                List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

                   // Select All Query
                   String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_TABLE;

                   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

                   // looping through all rows and adding to list
                   if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                   {
                       do 
                       {
                           labels.add(cursor.getInt(0) + " " + cursor.getString(1));
                       } 
                       while (cursor.moveToNext());
                   }

                   cursor.close();
                   db.close();

                return labels;
               }




    public void updateRow(Integer stremp_Id , String empName, String empDept, String empDesignation)
    {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put(Staff_Employee_Name, empName);
            args.put(Department, empDept);
            args.put(Designation, empDesignation);

        db.update("employee_details", args, "Emp_id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(stremp_Id) } );

    }


    public Integer deleteId (Integer id)
       {
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
          db.close();
          return db.delete("employee_details", 
          "Emp_id = ? ", 
          new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
       }

/******************************************Performance Table*****************************************/

        public boolean insertPerformance_Details(String strPerformer_Id, String strPerformer_Name, 
                                                 String strPerformance_Rate_One, String strPerformance_Rate_Two,
                                                 String strPerformance_Rate_Three, String strPerformance_Rate_Four,
                                                 String strPerformance_Rate_Five,
                                                 String strPerformance_Month,
                                                 String strPerformance_SecondDate,
                                                 String strPerformance_Year)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

            contentValues.put(Performer_Id, strPerformer_Id);
            contentValues.put(Performer_Name, strPerformer_Name);
            contentValues.put(Performance_Rate_One, strPerformance_Rate_One);   
            contentValues.put(Performance_Rate_Two, strPerformance_Rate_Two);
            contentValues.put(Performance_Rate_Three, strPerformance_Rate_Three);
            contentValues.put(Performance_Rate_Four, strPerformance_Rate_Four);
            contentValues.put(Performance_Rate_Five, strPerformance_Rate_Five);
            contentValues.put(Performance_Month, strPerformance_Month);
            contentValues.put(Performance_Only_Month, strPerformance_SecondDate);
            contentValues.put(Performance_Year, strPerformance_Year);

            db.insert(EMPLOYEE_PERFORMANCE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
            db.close();
            return true;
        }


         public List<String> getStaffEmployeePerformer_Name(){
                List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

                   // Select All Query
                   String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_TABLE;

                   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

                   // looping through all rows and adding to list
                   if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                   {
                       do 
                       {
                           labels.add(cursor.getInt(0) + " " + cursor.getString(1));
                       } 
                       while (cursor.moveToNext());
                   }

                   cursor.close();
                   db.close();

                return labels;
               }

}
```

Comment: Run your query in any GUI based SQLite browser! Check there and confirm whether you are writing a correct query or not!

Comment: @Paresh Mayani : above i have post the screen shot whatever i have run the same query in SQLite Database Browser.

Comment: i dont think that there is a left join in the android sqlite, checking this

Comment: @Paresh Mayani : Its working fine in SQLite Database browser and also i have show the runnable screen shot.

Comment: then the problem must be in your `DatabaseHelper`. How are you distributing your database?

Comment: BTW, how come you are able to write `openAndQueryDatabase()` inside onCreate()? I mean function inside function, how?

Comment: @@Paresh Mayani : I have create two table in my first table there are 3 columns and 11 columns .

Comment: @Paresh  :Sorry , I didn't get you what are function inside function.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter requires a field called `_id` in order to function properly, so getting the ID as _id would help I think

Comment: @ Zhuinden : Thanks for the help, my code is working perfectly. Thanks for the millions.